# How to hide the parent component when loading a child component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

In my current project, I have the following view

[image]

When the page loads, the `Parent Item Description` should visible and the `Selected sub item description` should not visible.

When I select a `Sub Item x`, the `Parent Item Description` should be hidden and only the `Selected sub item description` visible.

I have created the following route for this

```
{
        path: 'main/:id',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: MainComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full',
          },
          {
            path: 'sub/:id',
            component: SubComponent
          }
        ]
      },
```

But when run the project, it doesn't work the way that I was expecting.

I have added a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to load the sub item description, but when I go to the main item, the main item itself replicated inside that `router-outlet`.

In summary, I wish to load only selected item's description in the right side.

Comment: ng-show="! selected" for the parent item, and ng-show="selected" for the selected sub item text will do what you need (of course, you need to populate the selected attribute)

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo Yes it'll be work around, but I wanted to know whether is it possible it achieve with the router-outlet

Comment: Can you create a plunker or jsbin with a functional code? Now I understand your idea with router-outlet.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/WmppRxHmNxFHjDkmm1o0?p=info provides ready-to-use Angular2 TS templates. Please create a Plunker that allows to reproduce.

Answer (score 7):

You need to convert the parent route to a componentless route like this:

```
 {
    path: 'main/:id',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full'
        component: MainComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'sub/:id',
        component: SubComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it works partially, when I go to the following url: `main/1/sub/1` the sub item should be visible there, but right now, the sub item shows in a different page. Any suggestion how can it to be shown in the right side of the navigation?

Comment: When I go to the `main/1/sub/1` url, the sub item should be visible where it says `Selected sub item description` but right now, the sub component loads as a different page. How can I fix it

Comment: The working answer after searching the whole day.