# Hide parent view in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have to hide the above parent view.

[image]
Following is my code. When I click any one of the box parent should be hide child should be appear.

```
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
        <div class="container" [style.height]='height' style="margin-top: 7%;">
            <div class="row box_rpad">
                <app-box-layout 
                                (display)="onDisplay($event)" 
                                *ngFor="let color of colors let i=index" 
                                [color]='color.hex' 
                                [text]='color.name' 
                                [id]='i'>
                </app-box-layout>               
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- CHILD ROUTES -->
        <div class="container">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you not just use a service that the Parent Component subscribes to, and the child Component can the update the subscription "Hide" variable when clicked, or vice versa?

Comment: I have placed a bounty on the answer of @Vikash Rathee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make separate component for the one you called parent (ParentComponent) and for the one you called child (ChildComponent). You can then setup a route that loads either ParentComponent or ChildComponent into a router-outlet in your template. Doing so, the ParentComponent and ChildComponent are at the same route level. You have to change their names to make sense.

Comment: thanks for answering me. But its a nested component buddy

Answer (score 28):

In the parent component, inject the activated route like so:

```
class ParentComponent {
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute)
  }
}
```

Now you can use the `children` property on `route` to decide whether the current component is the leaf component in the route tree. Together with `ngIf`, this can be used to hide a part of the view:

```
<div *ngIf="route.children.length === 0">
  Some content that should only be shown when the user is at the parent component itself.
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In the example above, the `div` will only be shown if the user is on the parent component itself, but not if the user is on a child component.

Comment: This seems to be the simplest answer.

Comment: Amazing answer :)

Comment: Really Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 15):

*January 2021*

You can remove the component from the parent route. [See example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732620/how-to-hide-the-parent-component-when-loading-a-child-component-in-angular-2)

```
{
    path: 'parent',
    //component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      { path : '', pathMatch:'full', component: ParentComponent},
      { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent },
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. To quote a team member "I'm glad we didn't have to refactor the structure of the code"

Comment: @fundagain glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick.... not so optimal this solution, but at least it works as you want. So just wrap the things you want to hide inside a div with a boolean value, e.g

```
<div *ngIf="notSelected">
  <!-- your code here -->
</div>
```

And just set that boolean to false in the same function where you handle the event of clicking some box in the parent comp.

```
clicked() {
  ....
  this.notSelected = false;
}
```

To inform that the parent needs to be shown again when navigating back to parent from child, you can use `Subject`. So in your parent declare a Subject:

```
public static showParent: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

and in your parent constructor subscribe to changes:

```
constructor(...) {
  ParentComponent.showParent.subscribe(res => {
     this.notSelected = true; // show parent component
  })
}
```

and in your child, before navigating back to parent, whatever that event might be:

```
returnToParent() {
  ParentComponent.showParent.next(false);
  this.router.navigate......
}
```

Comment: yeah its work buddy. But after navigate home page there is no content. Home page become blank :(

Comment: @IamNaresh Updated answer :)

Comment: A reason for why unaccepting answer? :( Is there some problem with it?

Comment: sorry for that buddy

Comment: hi buudy if i refresh the page the parent div couldn't hide

Comment: That is normal behavior. You need to do some tricks to retain the data. Sessionstorage perhaps?

Comment: what can i do hear

Comment: You need to to retain the data somehow... maybe using session storage..? https://www.google.fi/search?q=angular+2+retain+data+on+refresh&oq=angular+2+retain+data+on+refresh&aqs=chrome..69i57.1311j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: i gave that but got another bug when i refresh or press back button in browser parent view doesn't show

Answer (score 0):

In the parent css:

```
.hide-component{
    display: none;
}
```

In the child component:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: HTMLDocument
) {}

HideBaseComponent(){
  let parent = this._document.querySelector('box_rpad');
    parent ?.classList.add('hide-component');  
}
```